# gcc warning flag for bogus comparison

Tags: gcc

I am searching for the right warning flag to use with gcc to detect something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  const size_t n = (size_t)-1;
  for( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) /* use `unsigned char` if you want */
    {
    printf( "%d\n", i );
    }
  return 0;
}
```

I tried:

```
$ gcc -Wsign-conversion -Wconversion -pedantic -Wsign-compare -W -Wall -Wextra -std=c99  t.c
```

What happened is that I have been modifying an existing code, that uses `unsigned int` for memory block size. The code starting failing with larger file. So I need to check I did not miss any remaining left over.

EDIT:

Just discovered `-Wtype-limits` but again this is not working for me

Comment: So what do you want it to warn about? Because I don't see anything suspicious about the code except of course n is never modified from it's too large value. But the compiler can't really see it. If it was a const size_t n = -1, than perhaps it could tell you it's always true. But otherwise I don't see how it could tell.

Comment: By the way the `-Wsign-conversion` is doing more harm than good. Because it warns about `size_t n = -1`, but that always means the maximal value of `size_t` and attempts to fix it make things worse, because in `size_t n = (size_t)-1` there is slight risk of modifying it wrong during refactoring and `size_t n = -1u` is outright wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out the trick, you need to use the c++ compiler instead:

```
$ g++ -Wextra  t.c
t.c: In function ‘int main()’:
t.c:6: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
```

with:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the compiler to detect that the condition is always true at run-time. This is barely within its possibilities in this case, because the reason it is always true is that one side is constant and the other is limited by the `unsigned int` type. I am glad that you found a g++ flag that did it, but if the value of variable `n` was provided in a different file, or not typed as `const`, for instance, the compiler may be unable to detect that the condition remains true.

You may also consider using a static analyzer that spends more time than a compiler on the detection of what may and may not happen at run-time. One open-source C analyzer is [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/try_out_value.html):

[image: function does not reach return]

In the screenshot, the statements in red have been detected as unreachable.

The open-source version only works well if the programs makes limited use of library functions, but even so, it can extract information that does not appear in g++'s warnings.

Comment: Both, gcc-4.7.1 and clang-3.1 detect that the condition is always true here (with optimisations). The test is removed in the generated assembly. They just don't warn.

Comment: @DanielFischer Interesting... This relates to a discussion about undefined behaviors and how compilers silently take advantage of them instead of warning for them (although there is nothing undefined here). http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html

Comment: Hmm, when I replace the for-loop with a `while(1)`, clang warns `always_true.c:12:10: warning: will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]`. So why doesn't it warn if I make the always-true condition less obvious, but it still detects that it is always true?